# No wired connection Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

This is a new installation on my windows 8.1 computer. I dual booted it with Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64x

I installed Ubuntu also on my laptop and an other computer. With the others Ubuntu works fine.

What info would you guys need to get a clue?

Comment: enter this command in a terminal " ifconfig " and then post the reslts

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Network Connections

2.If there is no item for Ethernet. click Add to add a new wired connection. 
  Once a connection is created, you can edit it to meet your network configurations

Comment: i tried except my computer see a wired and wi-fi connection but can't connect (i have the right password for wifi)

Comment: open Network ( not network connections) , there are on/off switches for both wired and wireless